# Qual o nome da convenção de código pra variáveis que usam _?

Tags: variáveis, estilo-de-codificação, convenções-de-nome, camel-case

Se variáveis declaradas assim:

```
var camelCase = "";
```

seguem o padrão *camelCase*, qual o nome do padrão para variáveis que usam o `_`, como abaixo?

```
ruby_var = "a questão vale 10 pontos =)"
```

Comment: Se chama snake_case: https://www.chaseadams.io/posts/most-common-programming-case-types/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geralmente é chamado de Snake Case, ou snake_case como alguns preferem. Esse estilo prega que qualquer espaço entre as palavras que formam um único identificador seja substituído por um *undeline*, já que o identificador não pode conter espaços. Alguns entendem que isso torna o identificador mais legível que outras opções como camelCase ou PascalCase que eliminam o espaço e tornam a inicial maiúscula para indicar a próxima palavra.

Eu acho feio, mas esse tipo de coisa é gosto. Claro, deve usar o que todo mundo daquela linguagem costuma usar, assim o seu código fica menos alienígena, por isso tendo a procurar adotar o mesmo padrão da linguagem, mas nem sempre.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).